# AJAX Content -- Server-Side Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a webpage that dynamically loads external HTML files and places them inside a specified `div` on the webpage.

so..

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"
Inherits="_Default" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body runat="server">
<div id="contentHolder">
 <button type="button" id="button1">Begin</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When `button1` is pressed, jQuery will use the load method to remove `button1` from the `div`, and replace it with `button2`.

```
<div id="page2">
<button type="button" id="button2">Next</button>
</div>
```

If I now wanted to reach some function on the **server** from **button2**, how can this be done? Keep in mind that `button2` is NOT a ASP.NET page so it doesn't have the ability to use `runat="server"`.

Comment: Usually the best option for this is using AJAX to communicate with the backend rather than using the code behind and ASP.NET postback option. But there's lots of ways, you gotta pick one and try it out.

Comment: Are there vulnerabilities in using either of those methods? This may end up handling usernames/passwords and I never like the idea of the client having anything to do with how that info is handled.

Comment: Well no matter how you look at it, the client will have to send data to the server. Whether it's AJAX or just a plain form submission makes no difference. What you should be concerned about are man in the middle attacks (which can be mitigated by using HTTPS) and having secure server password policies (strong passwords required, automatic account lockout etc). All things that aren't really related to which technique you use to send data to the server.

Comment: Thank you Mason, you cleared some of the confusion in my head!

Comment: I guess I have to ask one more question, are there any good tutorials out there on how to do this type of thing?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is not allowed on Stack Overflow. Anyways, it's unclear what you mean by "this type of thing". Do you mean how do communicate with an ASP.NET server using AJAX? Yes, plenty of tutorials out there on that.

Comment: I have to comment back, I don't see anywhere where it is shown working on content that are not .asp pages. All of the examples I have found rely on using constructs such as                                                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />                              The content I need to get to the server is dynamically loaded as .html files and placed inside of a holder div in my aspx page.

Comment: Plain HTML+JavaScript is perfectly capable of talking to an appropriate ASP.NET backend, doesn't have to be `.aspx`. And it's really no different than talking to any other backend. It's just JSON or XML or HTML over HTTP.